# how to get the latest row from the table for each vendor?

Tags: mysql, sql

[Query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyNba.jpg)

[Procurement table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeVIK.png)

My Query is not giving me what i want to get,

```
SELECT p.procid
     , p.procdate
     , p.vendor
     , s.sup_name
     , p.creditamount
     , p.image 
  FROM procurement as p
     , supplier as s 
 WHERE p.vendor = s.sid 
 GROUP 
    BY sid 
 ORDER 
   BY p.procid ASC
```

Query is giving me the first entry in the table for each vendor, while i want to get the last entry for each vendor in the procurement table(the required one's are highlighted in the image), any input will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: No pictures thanks. For next time, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated sub-query

```
select t2.*,s.sup_name from
 (
select t.* from procurement t
where t.procid in 
                ( 
                 select max(procid) 
                 from procurement t1 
                 where t1.vendor=t.vendor
                )
 ) as t2 join supplier as s on t2.vendor = s.sid
```

Comment: and how to get sup_name from supplier table in the same query which is related with the vendor in procurement table, need that as well

Comment: @Imtiaz you could join with procurement table by using properkey

Comment: Abadin, like how in the same query, please?

Comment: @Imtiaz answer edited please check and if it helps accept answer

Comment: Zaynul Abadin, awesome the query works perfectly, thanks for your support, much appreciated bro!

Comment: i guess its done bro, if not sorry for that as i m new to stackoverflow, show me the way to do that.

Comment: Zaynul do know how to put the where condition in that same query, as the query will gets the date range from the front end,

Comment: @Imtiaz just  use where  after join supplier as s on t2.vendor = s.sid this

Comment: SELECT d.debid, d.debdate, d.custcontact, d.debbal, c.custname, c.custaddress, c.custdescription FROM ( SELECT t.* FROM customer_debit t WHERE t.debid IN ( SELECT MAX(debid) FROM customer_debit t1 WHERE t1.custcontact=t.custcontact ) ) AS d JOIN customer AS c ON d.custcontact = c.custcontact WHERE d.debid >= '2018-09-26' AND d.debid <= '2018-10-03'

Comment: this one is giving me an empty result, while if I remove 

WHERE d.debid >= '2018-09-26' AND d.debid <= '2018-10-03'
will works fine.

Comment: @Imtiaz  you did condition on wrong column name you have to put date column d.yourdate date column

Comment: O yes, it should be d.debdate, thank you dear bro, now its sorted out just because of you.